# Installing Docker on CentOS

Tags: centos, docker

I'm working through the [docker installation guide](https://docs.docker.com/installation/centos/).  Running CentOS 7. I ran:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Output:

> warning:
>   /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/docker-main-repo/packages/docker-engine-1.8.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm:
>   Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID XXXXXX: NOKEY Public key for
>   docker-engine-1.8.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm is not installed. 
>   Importing GPG key

There's a little more after that about Userid, Fingerprint, from.

Next I ran:

```
sudo service docker start
```

Output:

> Starting docker (via systemctl): Job for docker.service failed. See
>   'systemctl status docker.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details. 
>   [FAILED]

I don't know what this message is referring to.  How can I fix this?

`systemctl status docker.service` result:

> docker.service timed out. Terminating.
>   Failed to start docker application container engine
>   Unit docker.service entered failed state

Comment: What does `systemctl status docker.service` show?

Comment: Updated question with info @jordanm

Comment: You might get better milage out of the docker packages that are distributed with CentOS, rather than ones provided by upstream.  Docker is included in CentOS's 'extras' repository, and is actually built to work with CentOS.

Comment: @jsbillings I'd love to try that.  I looked in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory and there is no file called `CentOS Extras`.  Do you know how to add this repo?  According to centos wiki it should have been installed an enabled by default: https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, I've checked this on a default installed CentOS 7 system and there the extras repository is indeed enabled by default - and `yum search docker` finds the docker packages. `yum info docker` prints 'Version     : 1.8.2' and 'Repo        : extras/7/x86_64'.

Comment: I have installed sucessfully in RHEL 7 and CentOS 7 kindly refer below URL.
https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/how-to-install-docker-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-and-centos-linux-7/

Answer (score 0):

Check if you get more details in:

```
journalctl -u docker -xe
```

Similiar driver issues - by default it is devicemapper and can be configured for something else:

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22371

https://mymemorysucks.wordpress.com/2016/03/31/docker-graphdriver-and-aufs-failed-driver-not-supported-error-after-ubuntu-upgrade/